# Finding non-unique rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, runtime

Say I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| Doctor | Patient | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 23 |
| Aaron | Josh | 46 |
| Aaron | Josh | 71 |
| Jess | Manny | 55 |
| Jess | Manny | 85 |
| Jess | Manny | 46 |

I want to extract dataframes where a combination of a doctor and a patient occurs more than once. I will be doing further work on the procured dataframes.

So, for instance, in this example, dataframe

| Doctor | Patient | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Josh | 46 |
| Aaron | Josh | 71 |

**would be extracted** AND dataframe

| Doctor | Patient | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jess | Manny | 55 |
| Jess | Manny | 85 |
| Jess | Manny | 46 |

**would be extracted**.

In accordance with my condition, dataframe

| Doctor | Patient | Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aaron | Jeff | 23 |

**will not be extracted** because the combination of Aaron and Jeff occurs only once.

Now, I have a dataframe that has 400000 rows and the code I have written so far is, I think, inefficient in procuring the dataframes that I want. Here is the code:

```
    doctors = list(df_1.Doctor.unique()) # df_1 being the dataframe with 400K rows 
    for doctor in doctors:
        df_2 = df_1[df_1['Doctor'] == doctor] # extract one sub-dataframe per doctor
        patients = list(df_2.Patient.unique())
        for patient in patients:
            df_3 = df_2[df_2['patient'] == patient] # extract one sub-sub-dataframe per doctor and patient
            if len(df_3) >= 2:
                # do something
```

As you can see, this is already verging on O(n^2) runtime(I say verging because there are not 400K unique values in each column). Is there a way to minimize the runtime? If so, how can my code be improved?

Thanks!

Umesh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may check with `groupby`

```
d = {x : y  for x, y in df.groupby(['Doctor','Patient']) if len(y) > 1}
d
Out[36]: 
{('Aaron', 'Josh'):   Doctor Patient  Days
 1  Aaron    Josh    46
 2  Aaron    Josh    71, ('Jess', 'Manny'):   Doctor Patient  Days
 3   Jess   Manny    55
 4   Jess   Manny    85
 5   Jess   Manny    46}
```

Comment: Had the same in mind ;)

Comment: This is the best answer. I have one more question for you. I see that the variable 'd' is a dictionary where the key is ('Aaron', 'Josh') and the value is the rest. Is there a way now to extract the numbers of the column 'Days' and put it into a list? Thank you.

Comment: @UmeshShreeman `[ y['Days'].tolist() for x, y in df.groupby(['Doctor', 'Patient']) if len(y) > 1]
`

Comment: @BENY, thank you for the response brother. Much love!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pd.DataFrame.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) like so `df.loc[df.duplicated()]`.

This selects rows where all values are duplicated, to choose for specific columns, you can set the `subset` parameter:

```
rows = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['doctor', 'patient'])]
```

Comment: Unless there is more that I need to add to your code, this code will only give me a singular dataframe with rows that have duplicates as opposed to giving multiple dataframes which contain the duplicates that I want. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: But you can then additionally apply a groupby-operation to extract separate dataframes. I like this answer. It is very explicit.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I have a question. From what I have seen, a groupby operation produces a dictionary. What groupby code would produce separate dataframes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df2 = (df.groupby(['Doctor','Patient'])['Days'].count() > 1).reset_index()
df2 = df2.drop(df2[df2['Days']==False].index)
df.merge(df2, on=['Doctor','Patient'], suffixes=('','_y')).drop(columns='Days_y')
```

```
    Doctor  Patient     Days
0   Aaron   Josh        46
1   Aaron   Josh        71
2   Jess    Manny       55
3   Jess    Manny       85
4   Jess    Manny       46
```